# Modx minishop2 - не работает модальное окно добавления в корзину

Tags: modx, minishop2, корзина

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, в магазине в карточке товара по нажатию на Купить открывается модальное окно с информацией о товаре и кнопкой оформления заказа, в этом окне все выводится правильно, но если добавить эту форму на страницу категории, данные в форму не вытаскиваются, такие как цена или заголовок товара на котором нажали Купить (выводится заголовок категории).

Кроме этого на странице товара есть список похожих товаров, которые выводятся через msProducts и последние просмотренные товары. При клике на Купить в этих блоках в форму подхватываются данные не нужного товара, а товара, на странице которого находимся. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать, чтобы вытягивались нужные поля товаров?